# Lion 10.7 Software Update Server can not connect to Apple

Tags: update, lion

Having an odd issue ever since updating my server from SL to Lion.

Software Update Server can not connect to apple to retreive new updates.

Here is the extremely non informative log:

> Aug 17 17:10:34 Pro-Server.local swupd_syncd[1001] : Performing
>   scheduled sync.
>
> Aug 17 17:10:34 Pro-Server.local swupd_syncd[1001] :
>
> Aug 17 17:10:34 Pro-Server.local swupd_syncd[1001] : swupd_syncd
>   10.7 (12) for Mac OS X Server 10.7 (Darwin/x86_64)
>
> Aug 17 17:10:34 Pro-Server.local swupd_syncd[1001] : ==========
>   Sync Started ==========
>
> Aug 17 17:10:34 Pro-Server.local swupd_syncd[1001] : Unable to
>   retrieve catalog(s) from the Apple server
>
> Aug 17 17:10:34 Pro-Server.local swupd_syncd[1001] : Sync
>   Complete

The machine itself can reach Apple's software update server when going through "Software Update..." in the menu bar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just had this same problem.  check to make sure that these two directories are there and have the right permissions:

/etc/swupd/               drwxr-xr-x   11 _softwareupdate  _softwareupdate     374 May 27 03:02 swupd

/var/db/swupd/          drwxrwxr-x    3 _softwareupdate  _softwareupdate      102 Mar  8 20:15 swupd

My var/db/swupd wasn't there.  after I recreated it and added the correct permissions updates started downloading.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I am unable to try your solution because I simply gave up and reverted back to Snow Leopard Server. Lion was causing too many headaches and I was running out of time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you behind an HTTP Proxy?

I know this is for 10.6, but this article may prove to be useful
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3099

Comment: Not behind a Proxy... Thank you for the article though.